# Django Class Based Views with popup functionality

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I wanted to ask if the following implementation is rational against Django rules of Views and Class Based views.
The scenario, I have implemented a mini administration section for users, not wanting to grant access to the general admin section of Django.
I am ok with the implementation and everything is working properly, recently I added also a small mixin to allow users to add related items the django admin way, the mixin is working properly (based on the original mixin of the Django admin interface). Just wanted to ask if this is a good approach or should I move to another implementation? (this is still a bit rough, made just for tests)

The mixin, we are actually checking against a query args, _popup, this is nearly the same way django admin checks for passed popups, this allows the form to load normally if working on it directly or as a popup when called through the parent form. partials/popup_reponse.html

```
class PopupMixin(object):
    is_popup = False
    popup_var = '_popup'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ''' Add the _popup to the context, so we can propagade the templates'''
        context = super(PopupMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.popup_var in self.request.GET:
            self.is_popup = True
        context['is_popup'] = self.is_popup
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.popup_var in self.request.POST:
            self.is_popup = True
        ''' If this is a popup request, then we are working with a form
        this means we save the form, and then override the default form_valid implementation
        this allows us to inject newly created items in the form '''
        if self.is_popup:
            self.object = form.save()
            return SimpleTemplateResponse('partials/popup_response.html', {
                'value': self.object.id,
                'obj': self.object
            })
        return super(PopupMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Then our create:

```
class TestCreateView(PopupMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = TestForm
    template_name = "add.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manager-list-tests')
```

This way in the view, I can make sure that first the base template does load only a bare form and not any other template parts, additionally I get to add a hidden field in the form:

```
{% if is_popup %}
<input type="hidden" name="_popup" value=1>
{% endif %}
```

Through this I override the default form_valid to respond with the same template as django admin uses:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title></title></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      opener.dismissAddAnotherPopup(window, "{{ value }}", "{{ obj }}");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say, looking through your code was helpful for an implementation I was working on.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi glad I was able to help you, though you can implement this as a processor :) got myself around that way which keeps views more clean and this kind of logic to a processor :)